# Git clone doesn't copy all files under Windows, yet it does on Mac

Tags: git, laravel, github

I've created a git repo for a new project with one branch made with MacOs system (it's a Laravel project).
Today I'm trying to `git clone` the repo on a windows system.

Strangely I have a lot of missing files such as pictures, views and layouts.

Someone knows why ?

I already did some tests with others mac, and the `git clone` command works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be in different branches so you have to checkout the desired branch.

```
# update your local repo
git fetch --all --prune

# list all your branches
git branch -a

# checkout the desired branch
git checkout <branch name>
```

---

#### How to see all file(s) in the current branch

```
git ls-tree -r --full-name HEAD
```

Comment: Files are in the same branch looks like (master). when I try git ls-tree -r --full-name HEAD command, all files are shown.

So I try git clone again, and still the same prob. Sorry but I'm begginer in git's world

Comment: If you see the files.  What is the problem?

Comment: The files are shown in branch master (terminal) , but haven't them in local after trying git clone

Comment: When I do a git status after clone command, alot of files have been deleted